# How to create a Range partition in Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure-synapse

I am in the process of migration Oracle 12c to Azure SQL Data warehouse, and i am currently creating the DDLs of Oracle tables.
My question is, how can i create "Range partition" by date in Azure SQL DW?
How do i convert this existing code in Oracle to Azure SQL DW?

```
PARTITION BY RANGE ("LOG_DATE") INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY')) (PARTITION "PART_01"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2018-10-02 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
```

Appreciate any help from your end.

Comment: I wouldn't automatically partition a table in SQL DW just because it was partitioned in Oracle.  SQL DW will already create 60 Distributions of your data across the nodes.  First I would make sure to choose the correct distribution based on any predicates or common joins to this table.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this statement to move any date prior to 2018-10-02 into one partition, then dynamically create new partitions for each day as rows are received.

There is no direct equivalent of this syntax in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

The technique that would appear to meet your need is dynamic partition management as described in the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition#table-partitioning-source-control